# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I'm still relatively new to programming, so my apologies if this has an obvious fix. I have been trying to debug this code. I've read through several questions revolving around this `addEventListener` error. It seems that most of them suggest to ensure that the elements are loaded in the DOM before the TS runs.

To ensure this I ran the method under `ngAfterViewInit() {}` and I also wrapped the core functionality within a `window.onload = function() {}`. I hoped these would fix the problem, but I'm still receiving the error. I will say that the TS, HTML, CSS functionality is working as intended. I hover over the letters and the letters change color and animate, however the error is just frustrating me. I will include my TS, HTML, and CSS. Thank you!

```js
constructor() {}

ngOnInit(): void {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.changeClass();
}

changeClass() {

  window.onload = function() {
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('wordPop');

    if (elements) {
      for (let i = 0; i <= elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
          elements[i].classList.add('animated');
        });

        elements[i].addEventListener('animationend', () => {
          elements[i].classList.remove('animated');
        });
      }
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}

.blastRubberBand {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: rgb(228, 15, 115);
}

.wordPop {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: aliceblue;
}

.wordPop.animated {
  color: orange;
  animation: rubberBand 0.7s ease-in-out 1;
}

@keyframes rubberBand {
  from {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1);
  }
  65% {
    transform: scale3d(.95, 1.05, 1);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale3d(1.05, .95, 1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="coolLetters">
  <span class="wordPop">H</span>
  <span class="wordPop">e</span>
  <span class="wordPop">l</span>
  <span class="wordPop">l</span>
  <span class="wordPop">o</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= elements.length; i++)
```

You are getting that error because on the last iteration, `i=elements.length`, and `elements[elements.length] == undefined`.

Instead, it should be:

```
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @YoussoufOumar stated, you are iterating too far. Array indices begin at **0** and end at **number of elements - 1**. The error you are receiving is caused by your attempt to reference a non-existent index in your array of elements.

For example:

```
elements = |a|b|c|d|
index =     0 1 2 3 
your last iter = elements[4], which is outside of the index range.
```